# denying browser notification permissions

Tags: browser, notifications

[According to the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission), you can prompt the browser to allow the user to grant or deny browser notifications. Once the user has granted permission, is there a way to programmatically deny that permission too?

Calling `window.Notification.requestPermission()` after they have granted permission does nothing except run the success promise.

My goal is to have an On/Off button toggle in the user settings portion of my site. As far as i can tell, there is no way to toggle off once toggled on.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible at the moment.

In the future we should hopefully be able to use the [*Permissions API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API) to check and revoke notifications (as well as other APIs like geolocation etc).

However, while we can currently query the status of a permission, the **revoke** method is unsupported. I believe it was possible in Firefox until recently, but in 51 the functionality was changed to default to off. 
As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API):

> The revoke() function has been disabled by default starting in Firefox
>   51, since its design has been brought into question in the Web
>   Applications Security Working Group. It can be re-enabled by setting
>   the preference dom.permissions.revoke.enable to true.

Example of permissions API:

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'notifications'}).then(function(result) {

  console.log(result);

});
```

Result is prompt/denied/granted. Change 'query' to 'revoke' for denying permissions.

```
navigator.permissions.revoke({name:'notifications'});
```

---

Alternatively, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28478605) from a couple of years ago suggests an alternate approach which you might find interesting - using localStorage to approximate this functionality.