# geolocation permission reset using Permissions API revoke

Tags: javascript, geolocation, progressive-web-apps, webapi

as I am working on pwa instead of revoking permissions from the browser settings panel, trying to revoke from the Permissions API but unfortunately getting this error

> navigator.permissions.revoke is not a function

please assist for the reference I took the geolocation :)

```js
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(result=>{
        switch(result.state){
            case 'denied': {
                navigator.permissions.revoke({'name':'geolocation'}).then(resolve=>{
                    alert(resolve.state)
                })
                break;
            }
            case 'prompt':{
                alert("need your permission")
                break;
            }
            default:{
                console.log("geolocation permission query: ",result)
                break;
            }
        }
    }).catch(error=>console.error(error))
```

Comment: It's good if you can mention which browser you tried this.

Comment: i tried it on chrome 83

Answer (score 0):

The Permissions Revoke API is not offered by all browsers according to [MDN Browser-Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/revoke#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Also newer browsers stopped the support. Did you verify? [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43473691/13745258)

Comment: i checked using,  `if(!navigator.permissions){console.log("no permissions api support")}else{consile.log("permission api available")}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```js
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(p) {
  switch (p.state) {
case 'denied':
  navigator.permissions.revoke({name:'geolocatoin'}).then(res=>{
    alert(resolve.state)
  })
case 'granted':
  console.log('granted')
  break;
case 'prompt':
console.log('prompt')
  break;
  }
});
```

Comment: ha ha just removed the {} from case :) no still same error